# The problem of using "map" twice in a React Native component

Tags: react-native

I have a problem that I cannot solve.
I have a string of objects which in turn has another string of objects

```
const data = [
        {
            title: 'Medical',
            data: [{
                notice: 'Test 1',
                documentType: 'Medical',
                file: 'https://test.1'
            }],
        }
    ];
```

And I try to load in a scroll view component those items according to the title

```
<View>
            <Header title={PERSONAL_INFO}/>
            <Center>
                <ScrollView w={["200", "300"]} h="80">
                    {data.map((item, index) => (
                        (<View>
                            <Center>
                                <Heading>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Heading>
                                {
                                    data[index].data.map((item) =>
                                        <Text>{item.notice}</Text>
                                    )
                                }
                            </Center>
                        </View>)
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </Center>
        </View>
```

Everything loads correctly with only one condition, I get a warning that I can't get rid of.

```
 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mapping over `item.data`

```
        <View>
          {data.map((item, idx) => ( <---- first array
            <View key={idx}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>{item.title}</Text>
                {item.data.map((subItem, key) => ( <--- inner array
              <View key={key}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{subItem.notice}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{subItem.documentType}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{subItem.file}</Text>
              </View>
                ))}
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

When rendering a list of items using React, [each element should be given a unique `key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). These keys allow React to [update its component tree more efficiently](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) by providing it a way to determine whether certain components have only moved and don't need to be updated. The ["Why does React Need Keys?"](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys) section in their beta docs has a good analogy for this.

That being said, you just need to give each outermost component rendered inside each `map` a unique key.

```js
// Assuming your item has some unique identifier property...
type Item = {
    id: string
}

// Example data array
const data: Item[] = [
    { id: "first item" },
    { id: "second item" }
]
```

```js
<View>
    {data.map(item => (
        {/* key prop used here */}
        <View key={item.id}>
            {/* This doesn't need a key because it isn't the outermost
                component rendered in the map
            */}
            <Text>Some example text</Text>

            {/* Anything can go in here, including another nested map.
                Just make sure to give each element a unique key in that one as well.
            */}
        </View>
    ))}
</View>
```

Also note that *React docs [recommend against using the index as a key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)* (see end of section).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give keys to the top level container of each item that you return when you're mapping, e.g. View and Text

```
<View>
            <Header title={PERSONAL_INFO}/>
            <Center>
                <ScrollView w={["200", "300"]} h="80">
                    {data.map((item, index) => (
                        (<View key={index}>
                            <Center>
                                <Heading>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Heading>
                                {
                                    data[index].data.map((item, idx) =>
                                        <Text key={idx}>{item.notice}</Text>
                                    )
                                }
                            </Center>
                        </View>)
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </Center>
        </View>
```

it would be far more ideal if you had Ids to reference, as using index as a key is an anti-pattern. but it's probably okay for your use case.